# trying to access the subscript of a Parse query array in SWIFT

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am having difficulty accessing the subscript at point zero of an array of objects that has been queried from Parses database. Code:

```
 var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geopoint, withinMiles: self.distance)
    query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: self.matches)
    query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: self.user.objectId)
    query.limit = 500
    var objects = query.findObjects()
    if objects != nil {
      for object in objects {

            var closestUsers = object as PFUser
            var closestUser = closestUsers[0] //COMPILER ERROR: Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
    }
```

As shown in the code I am getting a compiler error stating:  Type 'String!' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'` I can't work out why It is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var closestUser = closestUser[0]` is referring back around to itself. Did you mean `var closestUser = closestUsers[0]`? (though this code also looks wrong to me)

Comment: yes apologies, edited code now

Comment: Can you tell me how wrong?

Comment: you have an array of users made from a single user or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Think your reading it wrong, its just a basic query with whereKey filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to understand what your code is meant to do, but at a guess...

Try:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geopoint, withinMiles: self.distance)
query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: self.matches)
query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: self.user.objectId)
query.limit = 500
var users = query.findObjects() as [PFUser]
var closestUser = users.firstObject
```

In your code

```
var objects = query.findObjects() // Get response
if objects != nil { // Check if it is nil
  for object in objects { // Iterate over the objects

        var closestUsers = object as PFUser // Get the current user object (I presume here you want an array of users?)
        var closestUser = closestUsers[0] // Get the first user?
}
```

The `var closestUsers = object as PFUser` doesn't get the array of users but instead the current user object.

I presume you want the first user object from the array. In which case you can just grab the first object from the original array without iterating over it.

`var user = (query.findObjects() as? [PFUser])?.firstObject`

Comment: Glad to help, if this solved the problem please could you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is weird and you either typed something wrong or I'm completly not getting what you're doing.

Either way, you have an array of `objects` that are of type `PFUser`.

You put that array in another array (var closestUsers).
And then you apparently want a single user out of it.

have you tried simply doing it like so :

and not having to cast everything around like crazy

```
var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geopoint, withinMiles: self.distance)
    query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: self.matches)
    query.whereKey("objectId", notEqualTo: self.user.objectId)
    query.limit = 500
    var objects = query.findObjects()
    if objects != nil {
      for object in objects {

            var closestUser = objects.firstObject;
    }
```

You'd maybe have to add as `PFUser` somewhere but I don't know swift so I don't know where to.