# Convert PFGeopoint lat and long from Parse to display current users distance in radius to other users onto a text label

Tags: swift, parse-platform, location, distance

[image: result page not showing distance]

The first image is an example of what the result is returning and the second image is an example of the results page, 'distance' is the label that I need to change in order to display my users distance. I have all my users locations stored on Parse as PFGeoPoint called "location" in lat and long. I then have a tabelViewCell with a textLabel. All users are shown on the VC and I am trying to show how far these users are from the current user like in Tinder.

I have the other users locations running in the logs as lat and long coordinates and I have the text label updating from "distance" to "[] km away!" So I must be getting the array back but its returning empty.

I have searched the internet and can't seem to figure it out. All the tutorials are all obj c or json or to add annotations in mapView. Here is my code on my usersResultsViewController:

```
var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0
var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0

@IBAction func done(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToProfile", sender: self)

}

@IBOutlet var resultsPageTableView: UITableView!

var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var instrumentText = [String]()
var nameText = [String]()
var ageText = [String]()
var locationText = [PFGeoPoint]()
```

var usersLocations = Double

let roundedTwoDigitDistance = Double

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // start of tableView:
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {
// success

print(users!.count)
for user in users! {
self.imageFiles.append(user["image"] as! PFFile)
self.instrumentText.append(user["instrument"] as! String)
self.nameText.append(user["name"] as! String)
self.ageText.append(user["age"] as! String)
// self.locationText.append(user["location"] as! PFGeoPoint)

}
// reload the table forget this it will load nothing  
    self.resultsPageTableView.reloadData()

} else {
    print("error")
    }
    }
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // *** note to self: for the return here it must be a mandatory field for user look at this again nd change it to mandatory age or username or something.

    return imageFiles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let singleCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mySingleCellid") as! CustomCell

    // text
    singleCell.usersInstrument.text = instrumentText[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.userName.text = nameText[indexPath.row]
    singleCell.userAge.text = ageText[indexPath.row]

let query = PFUser.query()!

    if let latitude = PFUser.currentUser()?["location"]?.latitude {

        if let longitude = PFUser.currentUser()?["location"]?.longitude {

            print(latitude)
            print(longitude)

            query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo:PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
            query.whereKey("location", withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest: PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude - 10, longitude: longitude - 10), toNortheast:PFGeoPoint(latitude:latitude + 10, longitude: longitude + 10))

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    // success

                    for user in users! {

        singleCell.userDistance.text = "\(self.locationText) km away!"
```

here are some of the forums i have found helpful but I am still stuck!!!:

http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/a2d00e357960/ios-converting-a-pfgeopoint-lat-and-long-from-parse-into-a-cllocation-lat-.html
[trying to access the subscript of a Parse query array in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416107/trying-to-access-the-subscript-of-a-parse-query-array-in-swift)
[Two Query Constraints On One Key with Parse and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253733/two-query-constraints-on-one-key-with-parse-and-swift)

Comment: what are you really trying to do ?

Comment: @Lamour  
Im trying to update a label to show a users distance from the current user. The code above is probably confusing as its what I have tried so far and is probably all wrong. I am able to get print to the logs my location but I cant update the text label. I will edit my comment and show a picture of the outcome

Comment: so the distance between the two users?

Comment: @lamour yup I want to display the distance that the user is from the current user for example user ones coordinates are  5km from the current users position. So it should update the 'distance' text label to say 5 km away. Sorry if I am not very clear completely learning swift and parse as I go and tackling problems as they arise and just can't seem to find a solution online to this in swift language.

Comment: I think we need to create a **route** between the user one and user two, where the **first user is starting point** and the **second user is the destination.**

> Instead of showing a regular route onto a map, you just need to get
> the distance from starting point to destination point.

Comment: Ya that makes sense! I'll give that a go and let ya know! thanks.

Comment: @Grace what do you think about using the "near" feature and start getting all users within, say, 1 mile, then save that information, then get all users within 2 miles, then 5 miles, etc. The code to for each geo-fence is var southwestOfSF = new Parse.GeoPoint(37.708813, -122.526398);
var northeastOfSF = new Parse.GeoPoint(37.822802, -122.373962);

var query = new Parse.Query(PizzaPlaceObject);
query.withinGeoBox("location", southwestOfSF, northeastOfSF);
query.find({
  success: function(pizzaPlacesInSF) {
    ...
  }
});

Comment: @HenrySitu do you know of any tutorials on the "near" feature I have been searching since you posted and can't find anything to help me. I have edited my answer above to show what I have tried so far. The last two lines are causing errors.

Comment: @Grace yes, this tutorial has been useful for our clients https://www.parse.com/tutorials/anywall  Also, additional examples are available at https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud_code

Comment: @HenrySitu ya I have that anywall tutorial downloaded I didn't look at it in great detail though as its in objc c and I have zero experience in it, swift is my basic language ability. Maybe il just admit defeat and add a bridging header of a objc file. Thanks for the links though I'll have a read of them and try shed some more light.

Comment: @Grace here's one of the code snippet from the link above.  I'll post additional example code so you can mark this question as answered. // User's location
var userGeoPoint = userObject.get("location");
// Create a query for places
var query = new Parse.Query(PlaceObject);
// Interested in locations near user.
query.near("location", userGeoPoint);
// Limit what could be a lot of points.
query.limit(10);
// Final list of objects
query.find({
  success: function(placesObjects) {
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFGeopoints have methods called "distanceInMilesTo:" and "distanceInKilometersTo:".  These are what you're going to want to use.  Call that method on the PFGeopoint storing the current user's location, and pass in each user's location from your query.  Store the result in the appropriate label.

Here is the link to the API reference for this method: http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html#//api/name/distanceInKilometersTo:

Comment: How do I pull the other users location and use it?  I am able to pull it to print to the log but I can't seem to figure out the code to print it to my screen, like what is the way it should be written. Location a is the current user how to I write that location b is not the current user.                            singleCell.userDistance.text = "\(latitude, longitude CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = PFUser.currentUser(), distanceFromLocation: user)"???
var locationA: CLLocation = PFUser etc.
var locationB: CLLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: **other users*** longitude: ***]

Comment: Sorry its probably really obvious but I just can't work it out and i have been staring at all the documents for the past few days to no avail!

Comment: @Jake T. Thanks for the answer.  That's a great answer.  Got my vote.

Comment: @Grace Inside the for loop where you iterate through the users from your query. I'm assuming you stored their location as a PFGeopoint. Create a new PFGeopoint inside the for loop, set it to the user's location, and call `distanceInKilometers:` on the PFGeopoint of the current user, passing in the query user's location as the parameter.  I don't know swift syntax or I'd help a bit more.

Comment: @JakeT. Have been trying what you suggested nearly there aside from an optional nil. I will vote your answer when I get it sorted. Thanks for the help same to you Henry.

Comment: @Grace awesome, hope you figure it out. I really oughta pick up a bit of Swift, but haven't had the time. Wish I could be a bit more help, but you should at least be pointed in the right direction here.

Comment: Ya its definitely an easier language to pick up for someone like me who has zero coding experience!!! Anywho thanks for the guidance! I'll update the final result when its done!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "near" feature and start getting all users within, say, 1 mile, then save that information, then get all users within 2 miles, then 5 miles, etc.  Continuing to put geo-fences around a specific location and growing in concentric circles with increasing radius/distance, you can save the estimated distance for each user.

It's also possible to query for the set of objects that are contained within a particular area. To find the objects in a rectangular bounding box, add the withinGeoBox restriction to your Parse.Query.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(PlaceObject);
query.withinMiles("location", userGeoPoint, 10.0);
query.find().then(function(placesObjects) {
  // Get a list of objects within 10 miles of a user's location
});
```

More examples are at https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide

Comment: Henry I'm afraid none of that code worked with Swift. I have updated my Swift code to the latest parts that I've figured out. Thanks for your help I'm afraid I can't mark it as the answer though as I am still looking for it. Sorry.